# Sheaf morphism whose cokernel is not a sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-spaces, category-theory, sheaf-theory, functors

Let $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ be sheafs of vector spaces. I am looking for an example of a sheaf morphism $\theta:\mathcal{F}\longrightarrow\mathcal{G}$ whose cokernel $\text{Coker}(\theta)$ is NOT a sheaf. There is this typical example with the exponential function which I have already studied, but I would like to have a different one. Does somebody have an idea?

Comment: Take for example $X=\mathbb{P}^1$ and $\theta:\mathcal{O}_X(-2)\to\mathcal{O}_X(-1)$. Since these sheaves have no global sections, the "presheaf cokernel" has no global sections. But the sheaf cokernel (which is the sheafification of the presheaf cokernel) do have global sections. Hence the presheaf cokernel is not the same as its sheafification, so is not a sheaf.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! What exactly do you mean by $\mathcal{O}_X(-2)$ and $\mathcal{O}_X(-1)$ ?

Comment: This are the twisted sheaves : see here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_sheaf#Examples_of_vector_bundles